# Check to see if a value in one cell exists in another and append data

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have 2 sets of data, sheet 1 contains the following headings

```
email  business phone  Name    company
```

And sheet 2 contains

```
Name   email
```

What am I looking to do is dedupe the two lists and join them together ensuring the phone number field is attached to the correct record

So the end product should look like the below containing both sets of data:

```
email  business phone  Name    company
```

Does anyone know what the best way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This is not a service site. We can help you with specific question you have, but we are not here to deliver a completed product for you to use. Please add details of what you have tried so far, including scripts, code or formulas, and we will try to help. If you need more help, check out ***[ask]*** in the ***[help]***.

Answer (score 0):

You can *Remove Duplicates* using excel. Select the range that you want to de-dupe, and then go to DATA>Remove Duplicates. The window that opens allows you to decide which columns (one, several, or all) should be considered when looking for duplicates.

[image]

Think of using multiple columns like this: For each row, the values in the selected columns are concatenated and treated like a single column. This single column is then flagged for duplicates, and the corresponding rows in your original range are removed.

In this example, The range A1:D5 is selected before hitting *Remove Duplicates*, and columns A, C, and D are used as your criteria.

Before:

```
     A      B   C      D
----------------------------
1 |  Alice  21  Red    Dog
2 |  Alice  19  Red    Dog
3 |  Bob     1  Black  Cat
4 |  Bob     1  Black  Mamba
5 |  Bob    21  Red    Dog
```

After:

```
     A      B   C      D
----------------------------
1 |  Alice  21  Red    Dog
2 |  Bob     1  Black  Cat
3 |  Bob     1  Black  Mamba
4 |  Bob    21  Red    Dog
```